# Hashing without the use of JS

Tags: javascript, html, hash

Is it possible to hash generate SHA512 hash from strings/files in HTML5 without the use of JS? If it is possible, can anyone copy-paste the code here or point me to a reference site?

Comment: Huhh?  Please explain what you're trying to accomplish.  What do you want to do with the SHA512 hash is you're not using javascript?  What is the source of the data you want to hash?  There's insufficient information in this question to even know how to approach a response.

Comment: The target of the hash are user inputs. I'd like to explore and see if HTML5 is capable of generating hashes without the use of JS.

Comment: And, what's happening with these hashes?  Are they in a form being submitted to a server?  Without JS, I'm trying to figure out what you're even going to do with the hashes?  And, why do you want to do it without JS?

Comment: lol, post file/string to server (using html-form that targets parent/top window, new window or specified iframe). Let the server do the work and see the page refreshing (hopefully within 30 sec) with the corresponding hash (hey you weren't using javascript so no ajax etc.). Don't forget to collect your commission from the company that hosts your employer's website (they'll be selling a lot of wasted bandwidth this way). The real lol part is that there are actually quite some 'converter' websites out there that actually do this :) Alternatively, look into Flash or Java applets, etc.

Comment: You can do it with JavaScript in any decent browser. Why are you looking for a non-JS solution, exactly?

Comment: Hello, the hashes MUST be generated by the client, because sensitive information like passwords must be salted and hashed, and then sent to the server. I am looking for a non-JS solution (by using HTML5 purely) for experimentation and to have a counter-measure should the site break when a user has JS disabled.